# cron task to unmute my audio isn't working

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I set up two cron tasks to mute my desktop's audio at night and then unmute it in the morning (so that emails and other notifications don't wake me up):

```
lumpy@cheetoserver:~$ crontab -e

# At 10:15 PM every night, mute the volume
15 22 * * * /usr/bin/amixer -q set Master mute

# At 7AM every morning, unmute the volume
0 7 * * * /usr/bin/amixer -q set Master unmute
```

The audio is muted at night, but never gets unmuted in the morning. Yet if I simply execute the 7AM unmute command in the shell:

```
/usr/bin/amixer -q set Master unmute
```

...the audio is unmuted immediately.

I tested both commands before entering them into crontab, and they mute and unmute immediately (i.e, it doesn't take two unmutes to counteract a single mute, or anything like that).

Can anyone shed light on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found other posts by people having exactly the same issue. The problem seems to be that the cron job runs *without the necessary context*, and adding `export DISPLAY=:0` to each task is the solution:

```
lumpy@cheetoserver:~$ crontab -e

# At 10:15 PM every night, mute the volume
15 22 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/amixer -q set Master mute

# At 7AM every morning, unmute the volume
0 7 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/amixer -q set Master unmute
```

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll add that several solutions mentioned changing `set Master` in the two tasks above to `set Master playback`. This made no difference in my case, but if the first solution doesn't resolve your problem, you may want to try this.